# Is there a diff tool in GIT, which can just show textual changes and no formatting changes

Tags: git

We had a formatter.xml file introduced in our eclipse project to auto format the code. The problem we are having is now after formatting we see a lot of differences in the unchanged file when we do a

```
$git diff <file>
```

it shows few lines added and same number of lines removed, though there was no change introduced in the code.
 My question is there a command which can just show what actually changed and will not show the changes like the curly braces moved one line above because of auto formatting.

An example below:

```
-public class PPCCustomerFacadeImpl<T extends PPCCustomerData> extends      
DefaultCustomerFacade implements PPCCustomerFacade<T> 
{
+public class PPCCustomerFacadeImpl<T extends PPCCustomerData> extends 
DefaultCustomerFacade implements
+        PPCCustomerFacade<T> {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only differences are changes in the whitespace within individual lines, then `git diff` provides options that can help you; you might try `--ignore-all-space`.  [Here's a link](https://coderwall.com/p/crj69a) with more information.  If you want to make it easier to type, you can create an alias:

```
git config --global alias.diffis 'diff --ignore-all-space'
```

Then `git diffis` will run the diff with the option.

However, I believe it is impossible to ignore changes that move non-whitespace text to a different line, as in your example.  Tracking changes by lines is a fundamental principle of git.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Wally. looks like there is nothing available to achieve what I want :(. Though I would like to few more expert answer and will then select the appropriate correct answer among them.